# How can I automatically convert my formula references from explicit to structured?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have several columns in my tables and want to use structured references (table header names) instead of explicit (A1, CP34). Is there an easy way to do this instead of searching and changing the complex formulas individually/manually?